# Smart way to combine multiple Strings into a single String that can later be separated into the original Strings?

Tags: java, string

Assuming there are no restrictions in the characters that can be used in the individual Strings, and the Strings may be empty.

Edit:

Seems like the proper way to do this is to use a separator, and to escape occurances of that separator that already exist in any of the individual strings.  Below is my attempt to this, which seems to work.  Did miss any cases that will break it?:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>();
    strings.add("abab;jmma");
    strings.add("defgh;,;");
    strings.add("d;;efgh;,;");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add(";;");
    strings.add(";,;");


    String string = combine(strings);
    strings= separate(string);
    System.out.println();
}

static String combine(Vector<String> strings)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(String string : strings)
    {
        //don't prepend a SEPARATOR to the first string
        if(!builder.toString().equals(""))
        {
            builder.append(";");
        }

        string = string.replaceAll(";", ",;");

        builder.append(string);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

static Vector<String> separate(String string)
{
    Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>();

    separate(string, strings, 0);

    return strings;
}

static void separate(String string, Vector<String> strings, int currIndex)
{
    int nextIndex = -1;
    int checkIndex = currIndex;

    while(nextIndex == -1 && checkIndex < string.length())
    {
        nextIndex = string.indexOf(';', checkIndex);
        //look back to determine if this occurance is escaped
        if(string.charAt(nextIndex - 1) == ',')
        {
            //this ones is escaped, doesn't count
            checkIndex = nextIndex + 1;
            nextIndex = -1;

        }
    }

    if(nextIndex == -1)
    {
        //no more remain  

        String toAdd = string.substring(currIndex, string.length());
        toAdd = toAdd.replaceAll(",;", ";");
        strings.add(toAdd);
        return;
    }
    else if(currIndex + 1 == nextIndex)
    {
        //empty string 

        strings.add("");
        separate(string, strings, nextIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        //there could be more

        String toAdd = string.substring(currIndex, nextIndex);
        toAdd = toAdd.replaceAll(",;", ";");
        strings.add(toAdd);
        separate(string, strings, nextIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any control over the non-separator strings? A common approach to the problem is to define a simple delimiter string/character, and then bar any of the constituent strings from containing the delimiter.

Comment: @Hovercraft, for serializing/de-serializing a class composed of strings for persistence in a data structure that allows on a single string per mapping.

Comment: @dlev, this is a possibility. But I'd prefer not to restrict the characters, if possible and reasonably non-complex.

Comment: One common solution is to use a single character for the separator and to escape it (for example, by preceding it with a backslash) whenever it appears in one of the stings.  Of course, if the escape character appears in a string it will also have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, you can recover empty strings using the two-argument version of `split`:

```
String[] separate(String string)
{
    return string.split(SEPARATOR, -1);
}
```

If you can truly make no assumptions about the string contents, the only way to do this properly is by escaping the separator sequence (which can then be a single character) wherever it occurs in the source string(s). Obviously, if you escape the separator sequence, you need to unescape the result after splitting. (The escape mechanism will likely require additional at least one additional escape/unescape.)

**EDIT**

Here's an example (XML-inspired) of escaping and unescaping. It assumes that the separator sequence is `"\u0000"` (a single NULL character).

```
/** Returns a String guaranteed to have no NULL character. */
String escape(String source) {
    return source.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("\u0000", "&null;");
}

/** Reverses the above escaping and returns the result. */
String unescape(String escaped) {
    return source.replace("&null;", "\u0000").replace("&amp;", "&");
}
```

Many other variations are possible. (It is important that the replacements when unescaping are in reverse order from those used for escaping.) Note that you can still use `String.split()` to separate the components.

Comment: Any suggestions about the escape mechanism?  Possibly I should do something like use ';' as a separator, and prior to concatenating I replace any instance of ';' with ';;'.  And then I would have to parse the strings manually, because String.split cannot be instructed to ignore occurances of ';;'.  So, on my manual parsing I would look for odd numbered occurances of ';', and split on those (and replace doubles of ';' with single ';')?

Comment: I added my original post with an attempt to do this.  Any feedback?

Comment: Well, this is significantly simpler than my solution.  Mainly because doing two escapes/unescapes allows me to use String.split().

Answer (score 1):

Take your Vector of Strings and convert it to a JSON object and store the JSON object.

( http://www.json.org/ and http://www.json.org/java/ )

Answer (score 0):

You can build a class that stores the individual strings internally and then outputs a concatenated version of the strings when you call toString.  Getting the original strings back is trivial as you already have them stored individually.

Comment: Should have specified: I am concatenating them for persistence, and then re-parsing the stored String later.  When I re-parse, my previous objects will be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same comportement in two lines of code using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (Splitter and Joiner classes).

```
public String combine(Collection<String> strings) {
    return Joiner.on("yourUniqueSeparator").join(strings);
}

public Iterable<String> separate(String toSeparate) {
    return Splitter.on("yourUniqueSeparator").split(toSeparate);
}
```

Comment: `Joiner` doesn't work so well for `null` values. You need to pick a string to use as a `null` indicator and there are no guarantees that the null indicator you pick isn't present in the data. This is the same "questionable assumption" that OP was trying to avoid in picking a unique separator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at opencsv if you want to use delimited text.  The api is rather easy to use, and it takes care of dealing with escaping quotes and the like.  However, it treats null values as empty strings, so you might get a,,c if your input was { "a", null, "c" }.  If that's not acceptable, you could use a recognizable string and convert it back later.

```
char tokenSeparator = ',';
char quoteChar = '"';
String inputData[] = {"a","b","c"};

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(stringWriter, tokenSeparator, quoteChar);
csvWriter.writeNext(inputData);
csvWriter.close();

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(stringWriter.toString());
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(stringReader, tokenSeparator, quoteChar);
String outputData[] = csvReader.readNext();
```